# How does rasa achieve unit conversion

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, unit-conversion, rasa

I want to use rasa to achieve unit conversion.But now there are many units,like time,digital,length,mass,temperature,volume.And like the length unit has a lot, such as meters, kilometers, centimeters.There are many situations in combination.

How can I use rasa to quickly and efficiently achieve unit conversion? Please help me,Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can add duckling in your pipeline, it's a component that help extract these common entities.

Follow https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#ducklinghttpextractor

You can pull the image from docker hub and run it in container and the work is done. :)